# "Sourcetree determined this URL is in an unsupported format" when I check a .rc file

Tags: git, atlassian-sourcetree

When I check `.babelrc` git history I got the error "Sourcetree determined this URL is in an unsupported format".

[image: sourcetree an unsupported format]

Using `git log` works fine.

```
qiulang@qiulangdeMacBook-Air jssipwrap % git log -p -- .babelrc
commit a428050a4b563de019d23751b3988a02525096ca (HEAD -> master, origin/master, origin/HEAD)
Author: qiulang2000 <qiulang2000@126.com>
Date:   Fri Feb 24 16:20:08 2023 +0800
...
```

I find sourcetree will complain for other `.rc` files too. How do I fix it ?

Comment: Seems like you run into [this bug](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-6995)

Comment: Yeah, I misread the bug, it's apparently unfixed ... somehow the bug was closed (but not fixed) and duplicated. The dup is still open without any change ...

Comment: Do not edit the question to include the solution. The solution goes in the Answer field.

Comment: @matt I have added my answer.

Answer (score 4):

As @JoachimSauer has shown me in the comment, it is a [sourcetree bug](https://jira.atlassian.com/browse/SRCTREE-6995) and they have fixed it in **4.2.4**.

I also verify it works for all the `.rc` files.

Answer (score 0):

It's not great but as a workaround you can:

- Create a new branch
- Rename the file/folder starting with `.`
- Commit the change
- Now you can see history with `Log Selected`
- Check the `Follow renamed files` checkbox to see the full history